# How to parse all child fields and find what I need in Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I do password recovery and I need to know if there is a user in the database with the entered E-mail'om. How do I do that? Here is the structure:

[image: Structure]

For example, the user entered E-mail - goshan164@gmail.com and I need to know if there is such a mail in my database. And if it exists, then find out the uID of the user with such mail. How do I do that?

P.S uId initially I do not know. In the picture uId = zKCTYc1JkROrGxgOZgvm9CvfSU42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a Firebase database query, in this case one that compares the child property of each node against the value you're looking for:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users"); // or whatever your node is
Query query = ref.orderByChild("account").equalTo("goshan164@gmail.com");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on ordering an filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).